# Google apps script - Custom menu to run custom funtion

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've posted a bunch of times on this project, and am incredibly grateful for the help I've received :)

Something is eluding me: I have a Google sheet that contains 5 separate sheets, a Master and 4 individual sheets. I've written a "send emails" function for it that works as intended, and fires when a certain box within each of the 4 individual sheets contains "Yes."

My issues revolves around tying this script to a trigger. I received a previous suggestion to create a custom menu that fires the script upon selection. I was able to add the menu, tie it to a simple onOpen() trigger, and get it to appear in the sheet, but it would not run my script:

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
// Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
ui.createMenu('Send Emails')
  .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Send Emails For:')
              .addItem('Miranda Sheet', 'menuItem1')
              .addItem('Piper Sheet', 'menuItem2')
              .addItem('Lowes Sheet', 'menuItem3')
              .addItem('Golden Sheet', 'menuItem4'))
.addToUi();
}
//actions for menu items are below...
```

The intent of the script is to send emails, so I know now that I to tie the menu to an installable onOpen() trigger. That's the part I can't seem to nail. If I change the function name and tie an onOpen() through resources>all your triggers, to that function, my menu dissapears:

```
function addMenu() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Send Emails')
  .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Send Emails For:')
    .addItem('Miranda Sheet', 'menuItem1')
    .addItem('Piper Sheet', 'menuItem2')
    .addItem('Lowes Sheet', 'menuItem3')
    .addItem('Golden Sheet', 'menuItem4'))
.addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    //Prompt user for confirmation to send emails
    var responseMir = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to send emails?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    // Process the user's response.
    if (responseMir === ui.Button.YES) {
      //Test alert  
      //ui.alert('You clicked the first menu item!');
    }
}
```

So, my question is two fold:

1. Where's my menu?
2. After the function is tied to a trigger, how can I go about tying menu items to my script? It seems like I should be able to say "do stuff here" under the If statement above. Am I wrong in that?

Thank you for your thoughts! (I'm getting better I promise:)

Comment: When the end user selects _Miranda Sheet_ then whatever code is in the function `menuItem1()` will run.  Basically the menu item initiates the function, so you are correct on item 2.  You would call a function to send the emails, passing items specific to tje Miranda Sheet.

Comment: I would recommend keeping the menu defined in the Simple Trigger via onOpen().  See the restrictions on [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: OK, so what I am going to need is to have each menu item function gather the needed information from the individual sheet, then call a defined sendEmails() function, pass it the data, and send the email off? Wouldn't I then have to tie that function to an installable onEdit()?

Comment: no. onEdit isnt related. see the official "create a menu" help section for a template.

Comment: One other thing.  Do you have a function named onOpen() as well as the defined trigger?  If so, that could cause issues.

Comment: no, no functions with the same names :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear, there should be no installable trigger selected from the menu in regards to the `onOpen()` function as it's a trigger already.

Once the function is written and you wish to test out the options, you first need it to run. You can do this 2 ways:

1. Reload the spreadsheet (note that this will close your script tab!)
2. Run the `onOpen()` function

Note that once you have run the function to add the menu, you will only need to re-run it if you change the menu itself. If you made changes to, let's say, `menuItem1()` then you do not need to re-run the `onOpen()` as the menu selection will still run the latest saved code in the script.

Reading the comments I will second Zig Mandel, if you go by this route and use a menu to start functions, then there is no need for an `onEdit` trigger as they serve the exact same purpose — initiate data gathering.

Comment: Thank you! I think I was under the impression that if I used any trigger at all, it needed to be an installable one, since simple triggers can't send emails. But from what I'm gathering from the comments here, that's not the case. Using a simple trigger for the menu, having the menu item function gather data, and then passing it to a function that sends the emails will work just fine, correct?

Comment: @Jensen010 All the simple `onOpen()` does is add the menu. Once you click on the entry in the menu it's the same as going into the script editor and clicking run with that function selected. That's why after editing the function only, you do not need to re-run the `onOpen` unless you removed or renamed an existing function or added a new one. `onOpen()` simply ensures that whenever you open the spreadsheet, you will have that menu, nothing more, nothing less (unless you tell it to do some other things)